# KML size reduction

Tags: html, xml, kml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIJij.jpg)
I need help to reduce the KML file size, when i created the KML from xl macro, it is generating large KML file, is there any way to reduce the kml size, please....,

The KML code is....
It is creating the 350+ coordinates for each sector, may be this is causing higher file size.

```
 { << ? xml version = "1.0"
    encoding = "Windows-936" ? > < kml >
    xmlns = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0" > < Document > < description > < ![CDATA[Total >
        339 sectors 3 / 22 / 2018]] > < /description><Style >
    id = "my_style1" > < LineStyle >
    >
    < color > ff00ff00 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style2" > < LineStyle > < color > ff0000ff < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style3" > < LineStyle > < color > ff00ffff < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style4" > < LineStyle > < color > ff00aa00 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style5" >
    >
    < LineStyle > < color > ffff0000 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style5" > < LineStyle > < color > ffff0000 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style6" > < LineStyle > < color > ffff00aa < /color><color>ffff00aa</color > < width > 2 < /width></LineStyle > < PolyStyle > < fill > 0 < /fill></PolyStyle > < /Style><Style >
    id = "my_style7" > < LineStyle > < color > 501478 FF < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style8" > < LineStyle > < color > ffff0ff0 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style9" > < LineStyle > < color > ffaa00aa < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Style >
    id = "my_style10" > < LineStyle > < color > ffffff00 < /color><width>2</width > < /LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill > < /PolyStyle></Style > < Placemark > < name > < ![CDATA[Palu_Infill_1_31]] > < /name><description><![CDATA[<br><br><br><table >
    border = "1"
    padding = "0" > < tr > < td > Sector >
    Name < /td><td>Palu_Infill_1_31</td > < /tr><tr><td>Longitude</td > < td > 119.877 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > Latitude < /td><td>-0.886656</td > < /tr><tr><td>Bearing</td > < td > 0 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > Cell >
    ID < /td><td>1</td > < /tr><tr><td>Beamwidth</td > < td > 60 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > LAC < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>CI</td > < td > 7777 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > DL Frequency < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>MAXTXPOWER</td > < td > 7777 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > PCPICHPOWER < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>RNC >
    Name < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>Frequency_Carrier</td > < td > F1 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > U2000 < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>ACTSTATUS</td > < td > 7777 < /td></tr > < tr > < td > Antenna Height < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>Antenna >
    Downtilt < /td><td>7777</td > < /tr><tr><td>Equipment</td > < td > 7777 < /td></tr > < /table>]]></description > < styleUrl > #my_style1 < /styleUrl><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>119.877,-0.886656,0119.87675,-0.886222987298108,0119.876751260639,-0.8862222619106,0119.876752523382,-0.886221540193205,0119.87675378822,-0.88622082215203,0119.876755055141,-0.886220107793152,0119.876756324134,-0.886219397122614,0119.87675759519,-0.88621869014643,0119.876758868296,-0.886217986870583,0119.876760143443,-0.886217287301023,0119.87676142062,-0.886216591443669,0119.876762699815,-0.88621589930441,0119.876763981018,-0.886215210889102,0119.876765264219,-0.886214526203571,0119.876766549405,-0.886213845253609,0119.876767836567,-0.886213168044979,0119.876769125693,-0.886212494583411,0119.876770416773,-0.886211824874603,0119.876771709796,-0.886211158924223,0119.87677300475,-0.886210496737906,0119.876774301625,-0.886209838321254,0119.87677560041,-0.886209183679838,0119.876776901093,-0.886208532819199,0119.876778203665,-0.886207885744843,0119.876779508113,-0.886207242462246,0119.876780814427,-0.88620660297685,0119.876782122595,-0.886205967294068,0119.876783432607,-0.886205335419277,0119.876784744452,-0.886204707357825,0119.876786058118,-0.886204083115026,0119.876787373594,-0.886203462696161,0119.876788690869,-0.886202846106482,0119.876790009933,-0.886202233351204,0119.876791330773,-0.886201624435513,0119.876792653379,-0.886201019364562,0119.876793977739,-0.886200418143469,0119.876795303843,-0.886199820777324,0119.876796631678,-0.886199227271179,0119.876797961235,-0.886198637630057,0119.876799292501,-0.886198051858948,0119.876800625466,-0.886197469962807,0119.876801960117,-0.88619689194656,0119.876803296444,-0.886196317815096,0119.876804634436,-0.886195747573274,0119.87680597408,-0.886195181225918,0119.876807315367,-0.886194618777822,0119.876808658284,-0.886194060233744,0119.87681000282,-0.886193505598411,0119.876811348963,-0.886192954876515,0119.876812696703,-0.886192408072717,0119.876814046028,-0.886191865191643,0119.876815396926,-0.886191326237887,0119.876816749387,-0.886190791216009,0119.876818103398,-0.886190260130537,0119.876819458948,-0.886189732985964,0119.876820816025,-0.886189209786751,0119.876822174619,-0.886188690537326,0119.876823534718,-0.88618817524208,0119.876824896309,-0.886187663905376,0119.876826259383,-0.886187156531539,0119.876827623926,-0.886186653124863,0119.876828989928,-0.886186153689607,0119.876830357377,-0.886185658229998,0119.876831726262,-0.886185166750227,0119.87683309657,-0.886184679254454,0119.876834468291,-0.886184195746803,0119.876835841412,-0.886183716231366,0119.876837215923,-0.8861832407122,0119.876838591811,-0.886182769193329,0119.876839969064,-0.886182301678743,0119.876841347672,-0.886181838172397,0119.876842727622,-0.886181378678213,0119.876844108903,-0.886180923200081,0119.876845491503,-0.886180471741852,0119.87684687541,-0.886180024307349,0119.876848260613,-0.886179580900356,0119.8768496471,-0.886179141524626,0119.876851034859,-0.886178706183876,0119.876852423879,-0.88617827488179,0119.876853814148,-0.886177847622018,0119.876855205653,-0.886177424408175,0119.876856598384,-0.886177005243842,0119.876857992328,-0.886176590132566,0119.876859387473,-0.886176179077859,0119.876860783809,-0.886175772083199,0119.876862181322,-0.886175369152031,0119.876863580002,-0.886174970287763,0119.876864979836,-0.886174575493771,0119.876866380812,-0.886174184773396,0119.876867782919,-0.886173798129943,0119.876869186145,-0.886173415566683,0119.876870590477,-0.886173037086855,0119.876871995905,-0.886172662693661,0119.876873402416,-0.886172292390269,0119.876874809998,-0.886171926179811,0119.876876218639,-0.886171564065387,0119.876877628328,-0.886171206050061,0119.876879039052,-0.886170852136862,0119.8768804508,-0.886170502328785,0119.876881863559,-0.88617015662879,0119.876883277318,-0.886169815039801,0119.876884692065,-0.88616947756471,0119.876886107787,-0.886169144206372,0119.876887524473,-0.886168814967607,0119.87688894211,-0.886168489851202,0119.876890360688,-0.886168168859908,0119.876891780193,-0.88616785199644,0119.876893200614,-0.88616753926348,0119.876894621938,-0.886167230663674,0119.876896044155,-0.886166926199633,0119.87689746725,-0.886166625873934,0119.876898891214,-0.886166329689117,0119.876900316033,-0.88616603764769,0119.876901741695,-0.886165749752122,0119.876903168189,-0.886165466004851,0119.876904595502,-0.886165186408276,0119.876906023623,-0.886164910964765,0119.876907452538,-0.886164639676647,0119.876908882237,-0.886164372546218,0119.876910312707,-0.886164109575739,0119.876911743936,-0.886163850767434,0119.876913175911,-0.886163596123494,0119.876914608621,-0.886163345646073,0119.876916042054,-0.886163099337291,0119.876917476197,-0.886162857199231,0119.876918911038,-0.886162619233944,0119.876920346566,-0.886162385443441,0119.876921782767,-0.886162155829702,0119.876923219631,-0.88616193039467,0119.876924657144,-0.886161709140252,0119.876926095294,-0.886161492068319,0119.87692753407,-0.88616127918071,0119.876928973459,-0.886161070479224,0119.87693041345,-0.886160865965629,0119.876931854028,-0.886160665641655,0119.876933295184,-0.886160469508996,0119.876934736904,-0.886160277569313,0119.876936179176,-0.886160089824229,0119.876937621988,-0.886159906275334,0119.876939065328,-0.886159726924179,0119.876940509184,-0.886159551772284,0119.876941953543,-0.886159380821129,0119.876943398393,-0.886159214072162,0119.876944843722,-0.886159051526793,0119.876946289518,-0.886158893186398,0119.876947735768,-0.886158739052316,0119.876949182461,-0.886158589125852,0119.876950629583,-0.886158443408275,0119.876952077124,-0.886158301900816,0119.87695352507,-0.886158164604675,0119.876954973409,-0.886158031521012,0119.876956422129,-0.886157902650954,0119.876957871217,-0.886157777995591,0119.876959320663,-0.886157657555978,0119.876960770452,-0.886157541333133,0119.876962220574,-0.886157429328042,0119.876963671015,-0.88615732154165,0119.876965121763,-0.88615721797487,0119.876966572807,-0.886157118628579,0119.876968024133,-0.886157023503617,0119.87696947573,-0.886156932600789,0119.876970927586,-0.886156845920864,0119.876972379687,-0.886156763464576,0119.876973832022,-0.886156685232623,0119.876975284578,-0.886156611225665,0119.876976737344,-0.886156541444331,0119.876978190306,-0.886156475889209,0119.876979643453,-0.886156414560855,0119.876981096772,-0.886156357459788,0119.876982550252,-0.88615630458649,0119.876984003878,-0.88615625594141,0119.876985457641,-0.886156211524959,0119.876986911526,-0.886156171337512,0119.876988365522,-0.88615613537941,0119.876989819616,-0.886156103650957,0119.876991273797,-0.886156076152422,0119.876992728051,-0.886156052884036,0119.876994182367,-0.886156033845998,0119.876995636732,-0.886156019038468,0119.876997091134,-0.886156008461571,0119.876998545561,-0.886156002115397,0119.877,-0.886156,0119.877001454439,-0.886156002115397,0119.877002908866,-0.886156008461571,0119.877004363268,-0.886156019038468,0119.877005817633,-0.886156033845998,0119.877007271949,-0.886156052884036,0119.877008726203,-0.886156076152422,0119.877010180384,-0.886156103650957,0119.877011634478,-0.88615613537941,0119.877013088474,-0.886156171337512,0119.877014542359,-0.886156211524959,0119.877015996122,-0.88615625594141,0119.877017449748,-0.88615630458649,0119.877018903228,-0.886156357459788,0119.877020356547,-0.886156414560855,0119.877021809694,-0.886156475889209,0119.877023262656,-0.886156541444331,0119.877024715422,-0.886156611225665,0119.877026167978,-0.886156685232623,0119.877027620313,-0.886156763464576,0119.877029072414,-0.886156845920864,0119.87703052427,-0.886156932600789,0119.877031975867,-0.886157023503617,0119.877033427193,-0.886157118628579,0119.877034878237,-0.88615721797487,0119.877036328985,-0.88615732154165,0119.877037779426,-0.886157429328042,0119.877039229548,-0.886157541333133,0119.877040679337,-0.886157657555978,0119.877042128783,-0.886157777995591,0119.877043577871,-0.886157902650954,0119.877045026591,-0.886158031521012,0119.87704647493,-0.886158164604675,0119.877047922876,-0.886158301900816,0119.877049370417,-0.886158443408275,0119.877050817539,-0.886158589125852,0119.877052264232,-0.886158739052316,0119.877053710482,-0.886158893186398,0119.877055156278,-0.886159051526793,0119.877056601607,-0.886159214072162,0119.877058046457,-0.886159380821129,0119.877059490816,-0.886159551772284,0119.877060934672,-0.886159726924179,0119.877062378012,-0.886159906275334,0119.877063820824,-0.886160089824229,0119.877065263096,-0.886160277569313,0119.877066704816,-0.886160469508996,0119.877068145972,-0.886160665641655,0119.87706958655,-0.886160865965629,0119.877071026541,-0.886161070479224,0119.87707246593,-0.88616127918071,0119.877073904706,-0.886161492068319,0119.877075342856,-0.886161709140252,0119.877076780369,-0.88616193039467,0119.877078217233,-0.886162155829702,0119.877079653434,-0.886162385443441,0119.877081088962,-0.886162619233944,0119.877082523803,-0.886162857199231,0119.877083957946,-0.886163099337291,0119.877085391379,-0.886163345646073,0119.877086824089,-0.886163596123494,0119.877088256064,-0.886163850767434,0119.877089687293,-0.886164109575739,0119.877091117763,-0.886164372546218,0119.877092547462,-0.886164639676647,0119.877093976377,-0.886164910964765,0119.877095404498,-0.886165186408276,0119.877096831811,-0.886165466004851,0119.877098258305,-0.886165749752122,0119.877099683967,-0.88616603764769,0119.877101108786,-0.886166329689117,0119.87710253275,-0.886166625873934,0119.877103955845,-0.886166926199633,0119.877105378062,-0.886167230663674,0119.877106799386,-0.88616753926348,0119.877108219807,-0.88616785199644,0119.877109639312,-0.886168168859908,0119.877111057889,-0.886168489851202,0119.877112475527,-0.886168814967607,0119.877113892213,-0.886169144206372,0119.877115307935,-0.88616947756471,0119.877116722682,-0.886169815039801,0119.877118136441,-0.88617015662879,0119.8771195492,-0.886170502328785,0119.877120960948,-0.886170852136862,0119.877122371672,-0.886171206050061,0119.877123781361,-0.886171564065387,0119.877125190002,-0.886171926179811,0119.877126597584,-0.886172292390269,0119.877128004095,-0.886172662693661,0119.877129409523,-0.886173037086855,0119.877130813855,-0.886173415566683,0119.877132217081,-0.886173798129943,0119.877133619188,-0.886174184773396,0119.877135020164,-0.886174575493771,0119.877136419998,-0.886174970287763,0119.877137818678,-0.886175369152031,0119.877139216191,-0.886175772083199,0119.877140612527,-0.886176179077859,0119.877142007672,-0.886176590132566,0119.877143401616,-0.886177005243842,0119.877144794347,-0.886177424408175,0119.877146185852,-0.886177847622018,0119.877147576121,-0.88617827488179,0119.877148965141,-0.886178706183876,0119.8771503529,-0.886179141524626,0119.877151739387,-0.886179580900356,0119.87715312459,-0.886180024307349,0119.877154508497,-0.886180471741852,0119.877155891097,-0.886180923200081,0119.877157272378,-0.886181378678213,0119.877158652328,-0.886181838172397,0119.877160030936,-0.886182301678743,0119.877161408189,-0.886182769193329,0119.877162784077,-0.8861832407122,0119.877164158588,-0.886183716231366,0119.877165531709,-0.886184195746803,0119.87716690343,-0.886184679254454,0119.877168273738,-0.886185166750227,0119.877169642623,-0.886185658229998,0119.877171010072,-0.886186153689607,0119.877172376074,-0.886186653124863,0119.877173740617,-0.886187156531539,0119.877175103691,-0.886187663905376,0119.877176465282,-0.88618817524208,0119.877177825381,-0.886188690537326,0119.877179183975,-0.886189209786751,0119.877180541052,-0.886189732985964,0119.877181896602,-0.886190260130537,0119.877183250613,-0.886190791216009,0119.877184603074,-0.886191326237887,0119.877185953972,-0.886191865191643,0119.877187303297,-0.886192408072717,0119.877188651037,-0.886192954876515,0119.87718999718,-0.886193505598411,0119.877191341716,-0.886194060233744,0119.877192684633,-0.886194618777822,0119.87719402592,-0.886195181225918,0119.877195365564,-0.886195747573274,0119.877196703556,-0.886196317815096,0119.877198039883,-0.88619689194656,0119.877199374534,-0.886197469962807,0119.877200707499,-0.886198051858948,0119.877202038765,-0.886198637630057,0119.877203368322,-0.886199227271179,0119.877204696157,-0.886199820777324,0119.877206022261,-0.886200418143469,0119.877207346621,-0.886201019364562,0119.877208669227,-0.886201624435513,0119.877209990067,-0.886202233351204,0119.877211309131,-0.886202846106482,0119.877212626406,-0.886203462696161,0119.877213941882,-0.886204083115026,0119.877215255548,-0.886204707357825,0119.877216567393,-0.886205335419277,0119.877217877405,-0.886205967294068,0119.877219185573,-0.88620660297685,0119.877220491887,-0.886207242462246,0119.877221796335,-0.886207885744843,0119.877223098907,-0.886208532819199,0119.87722439959,-0.886209183679838,0119.877225698375,-0.886209838321254,0119.87722699525,-0.886210496737906,0119.877228290204,-0.886211158924223,0119.877229583227,-0.886211824874603,0119.877230874307,-0.886212494583411,0119.877232163433,-0.886213168044979,0119.877233450595,-0.886213845253609,0119.877234735781,-0.886214526203571,0119.877236018982,-0.886215210889102,0119.877237300185,-0.88621589930441,0119.87723857938,-0.886216591443669,0119.877239856557,-0.886217287301023,0119.877241131704,-0.886217986870583,0119.87724240481,-0.88621869014643,0119.877243675866,-0.886219397122614,0119.877244944859,-0.886220107793152,0119.87724621178,-0.88622082215203,0119.877247476618,-0.886221540193205,0119.877248739361,-0.8862222619106,0119.877,-0.886656,0</coordinates > < /LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs > < /Polygon></Placemark > < /Document></kml >
    >
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and data as text and StackOverflow's formatting capabilities.

Comment: In other words, are you trying to reduce the number of points for a polygon or line ? The example above shows the HTML for the description not the KML content for geometry, etc.

Comment: yes, actually im trying to plot the polygon by directional based,(In one location i need 3 polygon in different direction) when im doing for more sites, the resulted file size is heavy, is there any way to reduce the no of points to get accurate directional polygon,/Thanks

Comment: after KML conversion, by using genereated kml, is there any way/tool to reduce the file size, one i know that is: in google earth itself, when we save in kmz, it automatically reduce the file size, i need even smaller file, kindly help me if there is any tool to reduce the KML file size,/Thanks

Comment: Why would you post a picture of the KML?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all the unneeded styles (you are putting 10 styles in the file, but only using one).
2. remove the optional altitude from the coordinates [longitude,latitude,[optional altitude]]

```
119.87675,-0.886222987298108,0
```

is the same as:

```
119.87675,-0.886222987298108
```

3. only output 6 digits after the decimal point for the numbers (that will give you millimeter accuracy, should be good enough):

```
119.87675,-0.886222
```